# merge in pandas and output only selected columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Is there a way to do a merge in pandas limiting the columns you want to see?

What I have:

df1

```
ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1   1    1    1    D
2   A    C    C    4
3   B    B    B    d
4   X    2    3    6
```

df2

```
ID ColA ColB ColC ColD
1   1    1    1    D
2   A    C    X    4
3   B    B    Y    d
```

What I want:

df_final

```
ID ColA ColB ColC ColD
1   NA   NA   NA   NA
2   A    C    X    4
3   B    B    Y    d
4   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

I want to do a left join on two dataframes (keeping all IDs from df1) but I only want to keep the columns from df2. I also only want values if Col3 from df1 is either C or B.

The following works but the resulting df includes all columns from both dfs.
I can add a third line to only see the columns I want but this is a simple example. In reality I have much larger datasets and its difficult to manually input all the column names I want to keep.

```
df=pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',on='ID')
df_final=df[df['Col3'].isin['C','B']]
```

Equivalent SQL would be

```
create table df_final as 
select b.*
from df1 a
left join df2 b
on a.ID=b.ID
where a.Col3 in ('C','B')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mask `df1` with your `isin` condition before the `merge`:

```
df1.where(df1.Col3.isin(['C', 'B']))[['ID']].merge(df2, how='left', on='ID')
```

Or,

```
df1.mask(~df1.Col3.isin(['C', 'B']))[['ID']].merge(df2, how='left', on='ID')
```

```
    ID ColA ColB ColC ColD
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1    2    A    C    X    4
2    3    B    B    Y    d
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
df=pd.merge(df1[df1.Col3.isin(['C','B'])][['ID']], df2, how='left', on='ID')
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired output. OP wants 4 rows in the output, this only has 2.

Comment: I can't imagine how this answer is accepted when it does not even produce OP's expected result. -1

Comment: @coldspeed thanks. I have run both methods on my actual data and both are resulting in the same rows and columns..hmm. Could you point out what the difference should be?

Comment: @babz did you save your script after replacing my code with this?

Comment: @coldspeed, I did not just changed the code and ran it again